# Git checkout within a script inside the repository

Tags: git, github, automation

I have a git repository within which I have build.sh script. The build.sh does the following:

1. Checkout a different branch if needed (git checkout {branchname})
2. Recursive submodule update
3. docker build of the code

for step 1, the argument is mostly "master" other than code-freeze times. Since it is a fresh clone, I expect `git checkout master` to say `Already on master`. But it instead says `Switched to branch 'master' . your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 740 commits, and can be fast-forwarded`

When I clone the repository newly on a machine and run this script, I see an unexpected thing happen. Step 1, makes it go back to several commits in the past and starts building. Here are the relevant logs:

```
REGISTRY=xyz-ci.olympus.abc.com TAG=master FROM_TAG=master ./build.sh
05:33:54  Previous HEAD position was 38364c0cfd Update a-comp submodule
05:33:54  Switched to branch 'master'
05:33:54  Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 740 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
05:33:54    (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
05:33:54  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://devgit.abc.com': No such device or address
```

I tried the following to fix this:

1. Changed the default branch name from `master` to `origin/master`
2. `git remote set-url origin git@devgit.abc.com:WebApps/myProject.git` as step one before checkout.

Neither of them helped. It still goes back to an older commit. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Embed in the script the following `git fetch origin master:master` before actual checkout.

Comment: The `git checkout` itself *succeeded* as shown by the output messages. The step that *failed* was a subsequent `git fetch`, presumably one for a submodule. Remember, each submodule is a Git repository; each Git repository can need a user name and password, depending on how you have things set up.